# How the function auto.arima() in R determines d?

Tags: python, r, statistics, statsmodels

What is the test used in auto.arima() function in R to determine stationarity i.e to determine the value of "d" 
Can that logic be implemented in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/7) says it is determined using repeated KPSS tests.  I see no reason why it couldn't be implemented in Python, it would just need to be written.  Otherwise, you could use [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-dev/html/introduction.html) and just call `auto.arima` from python.

```
from rpy2 import *
import rpy2.robjects as RO

RO.r('library(forecast)')

# use example WWWusage data
RO.r('fit <- auto.arima(WWWusage)')
```